# Subset Inequality Problem

Tags: inequality, induction, natural-numbers, algebraic-logic

Here’s a problem I have been looking at recently.   I’m looking for feedback, references, and/or solutions.  Thanks.  FGS 3.13.23.

**Given**

1. A set $X$ of $6$ natural numbers $X = \{X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5, X_6 \}$ such that $X_1 > 0$ and $X_{i+1} > X_{i}$.
2. Let $L_2$ and $R_2$ be any subsets of $X$ having $2$ elements such that $L2 ∩ R2 = \{ \}$ (the empty set).
3. The true or false value of the equation $∑ L_2 ≤ ∑ R_2$ is known for each such pair of subsets $L_2$ and $R_2$ as defined in $2$.

**Prove or Disprove**

Let $L_3$ and $R_3$ be any $3$ element subsets of $X$ such that $L_3 ∩ R_3 = \{ \}$. Then the true or false value of each such $∑ L_3 ≤ ∑ R_3$ can be determined without doing any additions on the elements of $X$.

Additionally, if it can be shown that the subset inequality problem for $6$ element sets cannot be solved with zero additions, what is the minimum number of additions, call it $SIP_{min}(6)$, needed to solve the problem?

**Generalization**

The above can be generalized to sets having $n > 6$ elements.  Then determining $SIP_{min}(6)$ would be the induction basis step and $SIP_{min}(n)$ would be the induction step of a nice theorem.

Note that the Subset Inequality Problem is only interesting if $n$ is an even number.  If $n$ is odd then $SIP_{min}(n)=0$.

Comment: I assume that the 6-element "subset inequality problem" is exactly the "prove or disprove" statement. But I can think of all sorts of "generalizations" to other values of $n$. Which of those generalizations are you referring to?

Comment: I am interested in any generalizations you have.

Comment: This is your question. Get your house in order yourself. You haven't shown a bit of your own efforts, or explained where you are having trouble, and now you even expect me to do the dirty work of fixing it up for you? Come back when you get serious about it.